# Matlab referencing of part of string in cell array

Tags: string, matlab, cell

I'm looking for a way to reference parts of strings that are stored in a cell array. I need to do so in order to make a logical statement that will match strings I am looking for to the parts of the strings in the cell array.

Lets say my cell array looks like this:

```
cellname = { 'B_1J_1234_1236' , 'A_1W_2345_2349' , 'C_2J_9876_9879' , 'B_1W_5432_5438'}
```

And I am looking to find the string in the cell array that satisfies:

1. `'B'` as the first part of the string
2. `'1W'` as the second part of the string
3. The first number (third part) is less than 5434
4. The second number (fourth part) is greater than 5436

I know I can get an index of the element I am looking for that satisfies my first two search conditions by writing:

```
find(strncmp(cellname,'B_1W',4))
```

But I cannot find a way to include the latter conditions. Any ideas?

EDIT:
Ideally, I guess I'd like someway to do:

```
find(strncmp(cellname,'B_1W',4) & cellname{ "any element" } (6:9) < 5434 & cellname{ "any element" } (11:14) > 5436)
```

But it is the referencing of a part of "any element" that I can't figure out how to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very similar to Matt's but in one line

```
cellfun(@(x) strcmp(x{1}, 'B') && strcmp(x{2}, '1W') && (str2num(x{3}) < 5434) && (str2num(x{4}) > 5436), cellfun(@(x) strsplit(x, '_'), cellname(:)', 'uni', 0))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this problem by using `cellfun` and a self-defined function. In this function you can split the string in substrings using `strsplit` with the delimiter `_`. Then simply check if all conditions are met which returns `true` or `false` accordingly. Note that we need to convert the string in the third and fourth field to a number. This can be done with `str2double`.

```
function main
    cellname = { 'B_1J_1234_1236' , ...
                 'A_1W_2345_2349' , ...
                 'C_2J_9876_9879' , ...
                 'B_1W_5432_5438' };

    R = cellfun(@check, cellname, 'UniformOutput',1)
    find(R==true)
end


function out = check(in)
    S = strsplit(in,'_');
    out = strcmp(S{1},'B') && strcmp(S{2},'1W') && ...
          str2double(S{3})<5434 && str2double(S{4})>5436
end
```

*This is the output:*

```
R =
     0     0     0     1
ans =
     4
```

---

In case you want to use something similar to what you proposed, you can use `cellfun` as well:

```
find(strncmp(cellname,'B_1W',4) & ...
         cellfun(@(x)str2double(x(6:9))<5434,cellname) & ...
         cellfun(@(x)str2double(x(11:14))>5436,cellname))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions:

```
cellfun(@(x) ~isempty(x) && str2num(x.m)<5434 && str2num(x.n)>5436, ...
    regexp(cellname, '^B_1W_(?<m>\d+)_(?<n>\d+)', 'names'))
```